# Как пишутся названия блюд?

Tags: прописная-строчная, кавычки

Как будет правильно: *торт наполеон*, *торт Наполеон* или *торт «Наполеон»*? Точно такой же вопрос и насчёт десерта «Монблан».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я **дополню** уже данный ответ.

1. Если посмотреть на **частотность** употребления названия, то в Интернете встречаются два варианта: ***торт «Наполеон» и торт Наполеон.*** В то же время   ***торт наполеон*** используется редко.
2. Правильным надо считать вариант **торт «Наполеон»**, что соответствует **[правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=27#pp27):** § 23. Названия вин, минеральных вод, кондитерских изделий и т. д.

**Почему?** Можно обратить внимание на то, что в **некоторых темах** названия заключают **в кавычки как правило**, например: названия фирм, предприятий; названия литературных произведений; торговые названия бытовой техники, продуктов и т.д.
Это связано с тем, что эти названия **не ограничены** какими-либо правилами по содержанию и структуре (одно слово, несколько слов, различные словосочетания — все это **авторский выбор)**. Поэтому название пишется с **прописной** буквы и дополнительно заключается **в кавычки**.

3. Вариант ***торт Наполеон*** возможен **как упрощение**, так часто пишут пользователи в Сети. В принципе такое оформление (без кавычек) не запрещено действующими правилами, но используется **в других темах** (названия серий в технике, специальная литература для растений), например:

*Самолет **Boeing 737–800** — среднемагистральный пассажирский самолет. Большинство представителей тюльпана **Махрового раннего** – потомки старинного сорта Мурильо.*

4. Вариант ***торт наполеон*** — **нарицательное** название. Оно скорее обозначает  кондитерское изделие с точки зрения **особой технологии** приготовления (это торт, который можно так назвать).

**[Торт «Наполеон»](https://dzen.ru/a/Za5bnLYnlXVuRhSW)**

```
 Торт «Наполеон» – это легкое, распадающееся на тончайшие 
 слои, тесто и однородный, не дающий им окончательно 
 рассыпаться, ванильный заварной крем. В Италии и во Франции 
 его называют «Мильфей» (Millefeuille – Тысячеслойный), хотя 
 изначально у него было другое название – «Napolitano» 
 (Неаполитанский), которое до сих пор сохранилось в Италии, 
 в Бельгии и Нидерландах – «Томпус», в Великобритании – 
 «Vanilla Slice», а в России лакомство связано с именем 
 великого полководца.
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

[Ответы справочной службы: вопрос №275224](https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/275224#:%7E:text=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%3A%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0.,%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.)

> Поясните, пожалуйста, существуют ли правила, чётко регламентирующие
> написание названий блюд в меню ресторана? Если в случае с салатом
> «Цезарь» название заключается в кавычки, то как быть с блюдом, у
> которого название не односложное? Например: салат из авокадо с
> креветками. И нужно ли заключать в кавычки названия блюд, которые не
> являются общеизвестными? Например: салат палитра.

**Справочная служба**

> Названия кулинарных блюд могут быть собственными (индивидуальными)
> наименованиями, в таких случаях они заключаются в кавычки и пишутся с
> большой буквы: *салат «Палитра»,* но *салат из авокадо с креветками.*
>
> Трудность в том, что многие распространенные собственные наименования
> со временем переходят в разряд нарицательных и пишутся со строчной:
> *салат цезарь, салат оливье.*

---

[№ 288386](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4&mode=spravka#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4,%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE.)

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли названия блюд и напитков заключать в
> кавычки и (или) писать с большой буквы?

**Справочная служба**

> Возможно разное написание. Если название употреблено как товарный знак
> (например, в надписи на этикетке, ценнике), оно пишется с большой
> буквы в кавычках. В бытовом употреблении названия блюд, десертов,
> соусов пишутся строчными без кавычек, например: *мой любимый десерт –
> тирамису; к этому блюду надо добавить соус песто, он допил свою
> пинаколаду и ушёл.*

---

Розенталь. [§ 131. Названия фабричных марок машин, производственных изделий и т. д.](https://e-knigi.com/spravochnaya-literatura/spravochniki/page-56-296285-spravochnik-po-pravopisaniyu-i-stilistike-rozental.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

У Вас – торжественное: ***торт «Наполеон», десерт «Монблан».***

Comment: Большое спасибо!